# Editing the generated content of React after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-snap

I'm using `react-snap` to pre-generate my website content instead of client side rendering.

After building the project, when I manually edit `index.html`, the changes only get applied if the edited elements are outside `<div id="root"/>`.

I can add `scripts` and `meta` tags to the `<head/>` or to the bottom of `<body/>`; but nothing happens when I edit the content of `<div id="root"/>`. When I inspect the site the contents have not changed but the code inside `html` file is different.

What is causing this behavior and how can I bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to edit `index.html`?
By default, `create-react-app` uses `index.html` as a fallback.

Make sure you're not using self-closing tags like this:
`<div id="root"/>`

and replace with this:

`<div id="root"> </div>`

Comment: because the back-end wants to edit it for different content. there are like 5m of this page each with some difference.